# Why are my gameObjects not staying within the box I need them to stay in?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a Tetris game and currently I have my blocks and they move down automatically, right and left with player input, and the player can make them move down quicker. However the player can move the blocks out of the intended space and off the screen. It also never stops moving down and goes off the screen.

The box I want the blocks to stay in is 160x280 (width x height), and the bottom left-hand side is at (0,0). Each block is 20x20. Here's the code:

```
private float previousTime;
    public float fallTime = 0.8f;
    public static int height = 280;
    public static int width = 160;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        {
            transform.position += new Vector3(-20, 0, 0);
            if (!ValidMove())
            {
                transform.position += new Vector3(20, 0, 0);
            }
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        {
            transform.position += new Vector3(20, 0, 0);
            if (!ValidMove())
            {
                transform.position += new Vector3(-20, 0, 0);
            }
        }

        if(Time.time - previousTime > (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow) ? fallTime / 10 : fallTime))
        {
            transform.position += new Vector3(0, -20, 0);

            previousTime = Time.time;
        }

        bool ValidMove()
        {
            foreach (Transform children in transform)
            {

                if (children.transform.position.x > width || children.transform.position.x < 0 || children.transform.position.y < 0)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Depends where your box transform is relative to thr box. If they are 20x20x20 say if its the left bottom  corner then and position is 0,0,0 means its its all to the right and up. Where as if its in the middle the box actually occupies from -10 to 10. So you tell us why its not staying in your box :)

Comment: First of all, your downward movement does not check for `ValidMove` in order for it to stop going down. Secondly you need to share to us how does your game object that this script is attached to is layed out in hierarchy because we need to see the children of it.